# Any fast and simple way to hash small byte arrays so that most significant bits are most variable?

Tags: java, .net, algorithm, hash

The most commonly used methods to aggregate hash codes are also the ones suggested for generating hash codes from byte arrays. Typical examples (using `Aggregate` here only to get compact code for stackoverflow):

```
byte[] bytes;
var hashA = bytes.Aggregate(31, (i, b) => i * 31 + b);
var hashB = bytes.Aggregate(397, (i, b) => (i * 397) ^ b);
```

It seems the multiplications with relatively small, positive numbers will mostly affect the least significant bits for byte arrays with only a handful of elements. The same is true for the addition and XOR.

This is perfect when you want to do load balancing etc. via a hash mod algorithm. I currently however have an algorithm that is sensitive at the most significant side of things. **So are there any similarly simple and fast ways to hash, so that the most significant bits are more "variable" for small byte arrays?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, checking a couple of real test cases, it is not as bad as it seemed, and second, it is easy to enhance by just changing the seed value (see `hashC` and `hashD`):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (int count = 1; count <= bytes.Length; count++)
{
    var hashA = bytes.Take(count).Aggregate(31, (i, b) => i*31 + b);
    var hashB = bytes.Take(count).Aggregate(397, (i, b) => (i*397) ^ b);
    var hashC = bytes.Take(count).Aggregate(0xfedcbabc, (i, b) => (i*397) ^ b);
    var hashD = bytes.Take(count).Aggregate(0xfedcbabc, (i, b) => (i*31) + b);
    Console.WriteLine(hashA.ToString("X8") + " / " + hashB.ToString("X8") + " / " + hashC.ToString("X8") + " / " + hashD.ToString("X8"));
}
```

gives the following results:

```
000003C1 / 000267A9 / 3C4D958C / DCBA9CC4
00007460 / 03BAC114 / 8450EA1D / BA98FBBD
000E17A2 / C89D6C06 / 317B0EFB / 98867BE5
01B4DCA1 / 1C20854D / BBD63B3C / 784900BE
34E6B783 / 9E6EB86D / 4B39DC08 / 90D71706
67F038E2 / B1B4010C / A8BA386D / 8A0BC9BF
9616E364 / 94259F9A / A8C9810F / B76D6E27
2CC58923 / BE5881D5 / C07D2444 / 364056C0
6BEB9B45 / 2F415759 / 82113D7C / 91CA8148
1187CD64 / 4854750C / B4BC5945 / A785A7C1
1F71DF26 / 2AF98396 / 4816700B / 492F5069
```